# PHP compile: off_t undefined

Tags: php, compiler-errors, undefined, configure

Just a quick question: I want to compile PHP 7.1.6 and running into the following issue while executing the configure-script:

```
checking size of short... (cached) 2
checking size of int... (cached) 4
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking size of long long... (cached) 8
checking size of off_t... 0
configure: error: off_t undefined; check your library configuration
```

These are my configure options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --disable-all --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-zlib=/usr/local --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-ldap=/usr/local --with-curl=/usr/local --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local --with-iconv=/usr/local --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local --with-pcre-regex=/usr/local --with-pcre-dir=/usr/local --enable-filter --disable-debug --enable-inline-optimization --disable-rpath --disable-static --enable-session --enable-dom --enable-json --enable-ctype --enable-hash --enable-tokenizer --enable-xmlreader --enable-shared --enable-xml --enable-libxml --enable-simplexml --with-pic --enable-bcmath --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/local --with-png-dir=/usr/local --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local --enable-gd-native-ttf --enable-mbstring --enable-zip --enable-intl --enable-soap --enable-exif
```

Maybe someone of you have some hints for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my configuration (PHP 7.3.7 and Centos 7.6.1810), the solution was a mix of Anastas Giokov's response and kkuhrman's response:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PHP_DIR/build-src/srclib/libzip-1.2.0/lib"
```

and

```
ln -s ../lib/zipconf.h $PHP_DIR//build-src/srclib/libzip-1.2.0/include/zipconf.h
```

Answer (score 4):

The libzip version is not compatible with the php version. Using the latest version of libzip when compiling php7.3 will have this problem, and the downgrade will be fine.

```
wget https://nih.at/libzip/libzip-1.2.0.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libzip-1.2.0.tar.gz
cd libzip-1.2.0
./configure
make && make install
```

May have another problem：
zipconf.h: No such file or directory
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/13390

```
cp php-7.3.0/ext/zip/lib/zipconf.h /usr/local/include/
```

Comment: For me `libzip 1.2.0` cannot compile, `1.4.0` worked. (Install `php 7.3.4` on CentOS 7.3)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the issue is caused by the libzip library location missing from the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. In my case, I have added the lib sub-folder, while the actual library was installed under lib64. Adding the correct path solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was just to copy "zipconf.h" in /usr/local/include/ from the libzip source!
This file was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $ aclocal
```

...and /then/...

```
    $ autoreconf ./configure.ac
```

...lastly...

```
    $ ./configure
```

This solved the same problem for me. You may have to run ldconfig on /usr/lib64 if you installed libzip from source.

I encountered this problem again a little more than a year after the post above so this further clarifies the solution for my machine. In my case I'm trying to compile PHP 7.3 with a more recent version of libzip than the available RPM on CentOS at the time. I had to compile libzip from source, too. In my case builds of HTTPD, PHP and libzip were all installed to /usr/local sub-directories. I was able to get PHP to build by doing the following:

```
echo '/usr/local/lib64
>/usr/local/lib
>/usr/lib
>/usr/lib64'>>/etc/ld.so.conf
ldconfig -v
```

And then from my build directory:

```
./config.nice
make
make install
```

The hint for adding my local directories to my dynamic library configuration above came from this post:

https://programmer.group/lnmp-centos7-install-php7.3-nginx-1.4-deploy-and-install-wordpress.html

Comment: I encountered this problem again a little more than a year after my previous post. In my case I'm trying to compile PHP 7.3 with a more recent version of libzip than the available RPM on CentOS at the time. I had to compile libzip from source, too. In my case builds of HTTPD, PHP and libzip were all installed to /usr/local sub-directories. I was able to get PHP to build by doing the following: